# Carregar cidades através de um estado X, através de um arquivo.js

Tags: php, json, html-select

Tenho o seguinte código HTML

```
<div class="u-form-group u-form-group-7">
              <label for="estado_natural" class="div-sty">Estado Natural</label>
              <select name="estado_natural" id="estado_natural" class="u-border-1 u-border-custom-color-1 u-input u-input-rectangle u-radius-9 u-white" required>
                <option value="estado_natural">SELECIONE</option>
                <option  value="AC">AC</option>
                <option  value="AL">AL</option>
                <option  value="AP">AP</option>
                <option  value="AM">AM</option>
                <option  value="BA">BA</option>
                <option  value="CE">CE</option>
                <option  value="DF">DF</option>
                <option  value="ES">ES</option>
                <option  value="GO">GO</option>
                <option  value="MA">MA</option>
                <option  value="MT">MT</option>
                <option  value="MS">MS</option>
                <option  value="MG">MG</option>
                <option  value="PA">PA</option>
                <option  value="PB">PB</option>
                <option  value="PR">PR</option>
                <option  value="PE">PE</option>
                <option  value="PI">PI</option>
                <option  value="RJ">RJ</option>
                <option  value="RN">RN</option>
                <option  value="RS">RS</option>
                <option  value="RO">RO</option>
                <option  value="RR">RR</option>
                <option  value="SC">SC</option>
                <option  value="SP">SP</option>
                <option  value="SE">SE</option>
                <option  value="TO">TO</option>
              </select>
            </div>
```

E queria retornar no próximo select input somente as cidades do estado selecionado, vi algumas formas de fazer passando por um db, mas como não são todas as cidades do país disponíveis, precisava fazer a requisição através de um arquivo json que possuo nesse formato:

```
{
  "erro": false,
  "cidade": {
      "197": {
        "nome": "ABADIA DE GOIAS",
        "estado": "GO"
      },
      "25669": {
        "nome": "ZACARIAS",
        "estado": "SP"
      },
      "3407": {
        "nome": "ZE DOCA",
        "estado": "MA"
      },
      "27414": {
        "nome": "ABADIA DOS DOURADOS",
        "estado": "MG"
      },
      "2032": {
        "nome": "ABADIANIA",
        "estado": "GO"
      },
      "28254": {
        "nome": "ABAIRA",
        "estado": "BA"
      },
      "7600762": {
        "nome": "ABAPA",
        "estado": "PR"
      },
      "28463": {
        "nome": "ABARE",
        "estado": "BA"
      },
      "16305526": {
        "nome": "ABRE CAMPO",
        "estado": "MG"
      },
      "226": {
        "nome": "ABRE-CAMPO",
        "estado": "MG"
      },
      "28595": {
        "nome": "ABREU E LIMA",
        "estado": "PE"
      },
      "6892123": {
        "nome": "ZORTEA",
        "estado": "SC"
      }
  }
}
```

Como os Códigos de cada cidade são específicos, não conseguir implementar através do IBGE.
Também tenho outros select's que são condicionais e utilizam o mesmo padrão de arquivo json, a minha pergunta é, da pra puxar essas opções condicionais direto pelo arquivo ou realmente preciso passar para um sql? Estou fazendo tudo por php e js.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Dessa maneira?

**html:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="script.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="u-form-group u-form-group-7">
        <label for="country" class="div-sty">Estado Natural</label>
        <select name="UF" id="UF" class="u-border-1 u-border-custom-color-1 u-input u-input-rectangle u-radius-9 u-white" required>
        </select>
        <br />
        <label for="state" class="div-sty">Cidade</label>
        <select name="cidade" id="cidade" class="form-control input-lg">
            <option value="">SELECIONE</option>
        </select>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**script.js (atualizado)** (javascript com jQuery)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

carregar_dados_json('UF');

function carregar_dados_json(elemento, grupo)
{
 var html_do_select = '';
 var estados = []; //array para filtrar estados sem repetição 
 $.getJSON('https://api.npoint.io/cca1afd7773c92c72f42', function(data){
 
  html_do_select += '<option value="">SELECIONE</option>';
  $.each(data.cidade, function(key, value){
  if ($.inArray(value.estado, estados) == -1) {
        estados.push(value.estado);
    
    if(elemento == 'UF')
     { 
          html_do_select += '<option value="'+value.estado+'">'+value.estado+'</option>';  
     }
  }
  if(elemento == 'cidade')
   {
     if(value.estado == grupo)
     {
       html_do_select += '<option value="'+value.nome+'">'+value.nome+'</option>';
     }
   }
  });
  $('#'+elemento).html(html_do_select);
 });
}
$(document).on('change', '#UF', function(){
     var UF = $(this).val();
     if(UF != '')
     {
        carregar_dados_json('cidade', UF);
     }
     else
     {
        $('#cidade').html('<option value="">SELECIONE</option>');
     }
    });
});
```

Link com *novo* exemplo atualizado [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/vucs65xa/).

Comment: funcionou em partes, ele tem um problema se o arquivo.json tiver mais dados ele mostra todos os estados de forma repetida, para cada cidade vai retornar o estado dela, teria como remover isso?

Comment: Sim, mas precisaria entender como, de fato, é seu arquivo.json. Você pode atualizar a pergunta com o novo json ou informá-lo aqui.

Comment: Atualizei, pouca coisa mas é basicamente isso, tem bastante cidades e todas tem o dado UF, o problema desse código é que pra cada cidade ele retorna o estado dela, ai se tiver 200 cidades do estado de sp, no campo de inserir o UF, ele insere o estado de SP 200 vezes tbm.

Comment: se preferir "https://api.npoint.io/cca1afd7773c92c72f42" só trocar o link no jsfiddle

Comment: Nesse caso você precisa criar uma condição na qual os estados sejam adicionados ao array de forma a não se repetirem. Atualizei a resposta acima.

Comment: agora foi hehe, mas eu ainda to pegando o id da cidade na base da gambiarra, teria alguma ideia de como retornar o valor delas diretamente pelo input? exemplo, seleciono o nome dela mas receber o retorno somente o id.
Desculpa perguntar tanto, não to tão acostumado com js, agradeço muito a ajuda bixo

Comment: Não entendi exatamente o que precisa. Mas se minha resposta ajudou na solução do problema anterior, clique no botão para aceitá-la como correta. Você pode fazer uma nova pergunta pontuando a nova questão..

Comment: o id da cidade seria esse numero no arquivo.json (nesse caso "197")
`{"cidade": { "197": {"nome": "ABADIA DE GOIAS","estado": "GO"}}}`

Comment: Qual input? Não seria através do select? Você pode obter o ID através do parâmetro key. Vá até o [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vucs65xa/) de exemplo e abaixo do trecho `estados.push(value.estado);` adicione o código `console.log(key)`;

Comment: Se eu entendi bem o que você quer, pode ser feito [dessa forma](https://jsfiddle.net/natbco7f/).

Comment: Tu acha que daria pra ordenar em ordem alfabética?

Comment: Olá Léo Souza, nesse momento, devido a falta de tempo, não consigo te passar uma solução mais elegante, mas você pode tentar a seguinte: https://jsfiddle.net/ocpus4xd/

Answer (score -4):

Está utilizando JS puro ou algum framework como VUEJS? Você pode utilizar a propriedade Watch, Ela fica monitorando a variavel atrelada ao campo, quando você selecionar um estado ele irá gerar uma requisição buscando as cidades daquele estado:

watch: {
id_estado(newVlr) {
if (this.id_estado != null) {
const payload = {
id_estado: newVlr,
tabela: 'cidades',
};
let th = this;
axios.post('/admin/funcao/buscarDados', payload).then((response) => {
th.cidades= response.data.dados;
});
}
},
}

documentação para JS puro: [https://cgi.cse.unsw.edu.au/~cs2041/doc/MDN_javascript_reference/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch.html](https://cgi.cse.unsw.edu.au/%7Ecs2041/doc/MDN_javascript_reference/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch.html)

documentação para VUEJS por exemplo:
https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html

Comment: Mas eu preciso que funcione nos navegadores comuns e mobile, pela documentação desse watch ele não tem muita utilidade fora do firefox

Comment: Não procede meu caro, tem utilidade em todos os navegadores e mobile também, da uma lida melhor na documentação